# How to update input element using selected value from bootstrap dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

I would like to use knockout for updating dynamically the input element by the selected value from the dropdown but I don't understand how to use the code I commented here bellow with the dropdown and I'm not sure if it's the right way to do... Please help me understand and fix this problem.

[image]

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dropDownRelationType">Business relation type</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRelationTypeId" name="txtRelationTypeId" data-bind="value: companyModel.relationTypeId" placeholder="Business relation type"
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" id="dropDownRelationType" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: relationTypes">
                <li><a role="menuitem" href="#" data-bind="text: relationTypeId"></a></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Knockout:

```
function companyModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.companyName = ko.observable("");
    self.status = ko.observable("1");
    self.relationTypeId = ko.observable("");
    self.relationTypes = ko.observableArray();
}

function CompanyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.companyModel = new companyModel();
    self.relationTypes = ko.observableArray([
        { relationTypeId: "1" }, { relationTypeId: "2" }, { relationTypeId: "3" }, { relationTypeId: "4" }
    ])

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    //self.relationTypes.subscribe(function (selectedRelationTypeId) {
    //    shouter.notifySubscribers(selectedRelationTypeId, "valueToPublish");
    //});
    //shouter.subscribe(function (selectedRelationTypeId) {
    //    self.relationTypeId(selectedRelationTypeId);
    //}, self, "valueToPublish");
    //-------------------------------------------------------
}

var companyViewModel = new CompanyViewModel();
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(companyViewModel);
});
```

Comment: what bootstrap-modal tag doing here ?

Comment: The html code is inside a bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an observable to select the relationTypeId like

```
function CompanyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.companyModel = new companyModel();
    self.selectedRelationTypeId = ko.observable();
    self.relationTypes = ko.observableArray([
        { relationTypeId: "1" }, { relationTypeId: "2" }, { relationTypeId: "3" }, { relationTypeId: "4" }
    ])

    self.selectRelationTypeId = function(relationType){
        self.selectedRelationTypeId(relationType.relationTypeId);
    };
}
```

and change your html markup as

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dropDownRelationType">Business relation type</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRelationTypeId" name="txtRelationTypeId" data-bind="value: selectedRelationTypeId" placeholder="Business relation type" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" id="dropDownRelationType" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: relationTypes">
                <li><a role="menuitem" href="#" data-bind="text: relationTypeId, click: $root.selectRelationTypeId"></a></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

You should be able to see the selection you make in the input field.